# Continuity in general topological space (non-metric)

Tags: general-topology

When defining continuity using open sets in a general topological space without a metric, is this considered C^0 or C^inf or something in between?

Comment: What's a derivative of a map between general topological spaces? Heck, what's a derivative of a map between general *metric* spaces? (In short, it's $C^0$; nothing else makes sense.)

Comment: Figured that - thanks. Which leads to my next question :-)

Comment: Note that the same goes for metric spaces. Notions of Holder continuity can be formulated so you might see $C^{0,\alpha}$ in a general metric space, but you need more for differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a derivative requires a little more structure than a topological space provides. However, we can provide a derivative of a map between manifold. A manifold is a Hausdorff, second-countable topological space for which every point is contained in a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (locally Euclidean). Examples of manifolds  include spheres, the Klein bottle, tori, and many more. A non example would be a figure eight because the point where the two lobes touch is not contained in a euclidean neighborhood. A manifold $M$ is characterized by a collection of charts. A chart is an open set $U\subset M$ and a homeomorphism $\phi:U\to A\subset\mathbb R^n$. The collection of all the charts should cover $M$, and is called the atlas. We usually denote charts as $(U,\phi)$. If $N$ is another manifold, and $f:M\to N$, we can define the differentiability of $f$ at a point $x\in M$ by looking at charts. If $(U,\phi)$ is a chart on $M$ and $(V,\psi)$ is a chart on $N$, such that $x\in U$ and $f(x)\in V$, then the function $g=\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$ maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$. Though we have no way to define the differentiablility of $f$ directly, we say that $f$ has the same amount of differentiability as $g$, since $g$ is a map between real spaces witha well defined method for determining derivatives.

Comment: a topological manifold is homeomorphic to the space of reals, but it is not necessarily homeomorphic to euclidean space. A smooth or differentiable manifold is ... and homeomorphic to euclidean space.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the heads up.